# SCIM API (C#) for provisionng Users from Azure AD to SaaS applications

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, webapi, scim

I am looking at the below documentation for building SCIM API

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/app-provisioning/use-scim-to-provision-users-and-groups#step-3-build-a-scim-endpoint

I talks of below classes but i cannot find the Nuget packages for the same. Any one knowwhere to find those. I see Microsoft.SystemForCrossDomainIdentityManagement package but thats not available in .NET Core

```
// System.Threading.Tasks.Tasks is defined in mscorlib.dll.  
// Microsoft.SCIM.IRequest is defined in 
// Microsoft.SCIM.Service.   
// Microsoft.SCIM.Resource is defined in 
// Microsoft.SCIM.Schemas.  
// Microsoft.SCIM.IQueryParameters is defined in 
// Microsoft.SCIM.Protocol.
```

Comment: Have you gone through the [code](https://aka.ms/SCIMReferenceCode) provided. Where there is no need to nuget packages for implementing SCIM API, and also currently there is no proper documentation for Microsoft.SystemForCrossDomainIdentityManagement package. There is already [request raised](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/42230) on the package documentation

Answer (score 0):

As @Raghavendra mentioned we need to use the reference code from https://github.com/AzureAD/SCIMReferenceCode